# Is the ideal generated by ${4,x}$ a principal ideal in $Z[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I've : $I=<p,x>$ is not a principal ideal in $Z[x]$ where p is prime.
My question :   Is $I=<p,x>$ a principal ideal in $Z[x]$ where p is not a prime?
More particularly, is the ideal generated by ${4,x}$ a principal ideal in $Z[x]$ ?

Comment: If you have already that $I=(p,x)$ is not maximal, then where did you use there that $p$ is prime? Can you replace $2$ by $4$ in the [standard proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097008/2-x-is-not-a-principal-ideal-of-the-ring-mathbbzx?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3045090/58401) of mine.

Answer (score 1):

If $\langle4,x\rangle$ was a principal ideal, then you would have $\langle4,x\rangle=\langle p(x)\rangle$, for some $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Is this true? What can you tell about a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if you know that $p(x)\mid4$ and that $p(x)\mid x$?

Comment: Ok. I've got this. Thanks.